# Is it possible to change category names or create new category if category is available programmatically magento 2?

Tags: magento2, category

> Actually i am trying to change category names with a bunch of data(csv data) or create a new category
>   if the category is not available programmatically Magento 2

Comment: How you have check a category is exits  or  not?

Comment: hi Amit Bera sir,Actually we can read the category and match with available data with some logic.

Comment: whta is the logic?

Comment: https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/import-magento-2-categories-programmatically/

Answer (score 1):

**if you want to change category name use below code it's helpful for you.**

**-> You can set store id**

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
// require __DIR__ . '../../csv/Customer.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$category = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load(3);
$d["entity_id"] = "3";
$d["is_active"] = "1";

$d["name"] = "TESTA-2_ENG";

// $d["url_key"] = "testa-1-eng";
$d["store_id"] = "0";
$category->setData($d);
$category->save();
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface')->save($category);
```